# How to set the permission?

Tags: windows

I backup my SQL data on computer WINX using a batch file and create the file in the folder
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup" of Windows Server WIN2016. I share the this folder as \WIN2016\BACKUP.

Then on computer WINX I copy the .bak from \WIN2016\BACKUP to another disk and want to delete the files in \WIN2016\BACKUP. However I get an error message "You require permission from MSSQLSERVER to make changes to this file".

WINX is a Windows 10 virtual machine in WIN2016. Both computers have not joined any domain.

On WIN2016, I (Ben Tam) have full control on the folder. However I am deleting the files at computer WINX. Is there any way to add WINX\BEN to the admin group of WIN2016.

My question is how to make the files in the folder deletable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by:

1. removing [everyone] in the [Advance Sharing]-[Permissions] list
2. adding back [WINX\Ben] with [Full Control]

Ben